# Tokudb 5.7 [Warning] The partition engine is deprecated and will be removed in a future release

Tags: mysql, upgrade, percona, tokudb

I am running upgrade from Tokudb 5.6.30 to 5.7.17 (Percona distribution) and I am getting this warning

> [Warning] The partition engine, used by table ‘my_table’, is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use native partitioning instead.

Does it mean that I can still use it in 5.7.17 tokudb, but to use native partitioning in a future releases (8.0) I will have to rebuild this table to use innodb. In other words, is Percona or any other distribution going to support partioning in Tokudb beyond 5.7?

Answer (score 1):

It remains to be seen.

Oracle's MySQL 8.0 is

- Moving partitioning support into the InnoDB engine.
- Removing MyISAM.
- Building a "Data Dictionary" (in InnoDB tables) that replaces .frm files, etc.

This leads to action items for the "forks" -- MariaDB, Percona, Aurora, etc.:

- Continue to keep MyISAM, TokuDB, Aria, etc.?  Or abandon?
- Abandon Partitioning for that engine?  Or re-implement it?
- Implement usage of the Data Dictionary for that engine?  Or keep old mechanism?

Attend Percona Live in April; there will be plenty of Percona, etc, folks there to address the question (if they have decided by then).